# How to programmatically get the type of a variable and use it as a function parameter's type?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I have a type question for TypeScript 4.1.5.

Consider the following example.  I make a GraphQL query in `getItems`, and the result `items` implicitly knows the unnamed generated type from calling this function.  Later, I want to do a map operation, where I am required to specify a type for each element.

```
const items = getItems();  // calling a GraphQL query

const transformedItems = items.map((item: any) => {
  return {
    // transformation logic here
  };
});
```

Hovering over `items` in VSCode reveals the type is an array of an unnamed generated type that specifically contains the attributes and connectors I asked for in the GraphQL query in `getItems`:

```
const items: ({
    __typename?: "myItem" | undefined;
} & Pick<myItem, "id" | "createdAt" | "updatedAt" | "apiId" | "lastUpdated" | "balanceAfterThis" | ... 23 more ... | "apiCreatedAt">)[]
```

For now I just used `any` type because I could not import that generated type and use it here.  (I think `graphql-codegen` did not bother giving it a name to export it.) I understand this `any` type solution would mask errors that would've been caught if I could specify the correct type here.  I want to use the correct type, but I'm not sure how to do it.

(Also I do not want to rewrite the map operation as a loop just to avoid the type problem.)

(Also I do not want to manually write out this generated type, because the GraphQL function could change later, and I would have to change my manual type definition too.)

Is there some way to programmatically get the type stored in `items` and use it in the map operation?  Or perhaps there is another way to solve this type problem?  Please let me know.  Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your problem can be resolved by my framework perfectly.

https://github.com/babyfish-ct/graphql-ts-client

This GraphQL typescript client can automatically infers the type of the returned data according to the strongly typed query request, no other similar client frameworks can do it.

[image]

You see, all the queried fields can be suggested by IDE! it unifies both the dynamics and strong typing.

The returned type is inferred automatically, so you can write your map function as you wish.